# C# Azure BlobTrigger -> Get the URL of the uploaded blob

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How can I get the URL of the BLOB which triggers the "BLOBTrigger"?
Getting the name works with the {name} section but I also need the URL.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync(
            [BlobTrigger("input/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlob,
            [Blob("output/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream outputBlob,
            string name,
            ILogger log)
        {
            
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name}");
            //log.LogInformation("HERE I NEED THE URL");
            log.LogInformation("*******************----**********************");            
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input as CloudBlockBlob, then you can get the properties. Blob path is in the properties.

Comment: I had already tried that before but I had trouble copying the new blob into another. After your post I tried again it's working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Miles Hi, If my answer answered your question, can you [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2eE3.jpg) to end this question? Thanks.:)